# What SQL-server function can I use to get the character or byte length of a nvarchar(max) column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column which is of type nvarchar(max).  How do I find the length of the string (or the number of bytes) for the column for each row in the table?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> SELECT LEN(columnName) AS MyLength
>   FROM myTable

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out the max there should be a way for you to get the schema of the table.  Normally you can do something like [SHOW COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html) in SQL or a [DESCRIBE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html) style command.  In a mysql shell that can be shortened to:

```
desc tablename;
```

Then if you want to determine the length of a string there is normally a function like [LENGTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) *(for bytes)* or [CHAR_LENGTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) *(for characters)*.

```
SELECT *, LENGTH(fieldname) AS len FROM tablename
```

Comment: The question specifically states sql-server and you replied with some mysql links...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT LEN(columnName) AS MyLength FROM myTable
```

I used this query for my table. It displays the size of each row in a particular column.

I need that field name size maximum it allow the characters.